# Difference between int[,] array = new int[4, 2]; and int[] test = { 4, 2 };

Tags: c#, arrays

I recently discovered that two ways to declare array in C#, those are:

- `int[,] array = new int[4, 2];`
- `int[] test = { 4, 2 };`

Could anyone please describe the difference between those two statements?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays), though I'm going to assume you know what `int[]` is and you really want to know about `int[][]`.

Comment: `int[,] array = new int[4, 2];` - 2d array `4x2`. `int[] test = { 4, 2 };` 1d array with 2 items which are `2` and `4`

Comment: `int[,]` is 2-dimensional. It is a matrix having rows and columns. Elements must be accessed through 2 indexes: `int element = array[x, y];`. `int[]` has one dimension and one index is required: `int element = text[i];`. An array can have up to 32 dimensions (32 indexes).

Comment: @gunr2171 OP never mentioned jagged arrays (`int[][]`), they have a multidimensional array and a basic array with implicit initialization.

Comment: I'd argue that `int[]` is a multidimensional array with a dimension of 1, and `int[][]` is a dimension of 2.

Comment: here's another way to declare an array that makes things really confusing, `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 0, byte.MaxValue, short.MaxValue, int.MaxValue }, new[] { int.MinValue, short.MinValue, byte.MinValue, 0 });`

Answer (score 3):

```
int[,] array = new int[4, 2];
```

creates array with `8` elements having the default value of `0` and `2` dimensions

```
int[] test = { 4, 2 };
```

creates array with `2` elements(`4` and `2`) and `1` dimension